# Debian wheezy pam and samba

Tags: linux, debian, samba, pam

I installed a Debian server into a Windows controlled domain. I then tried to give to LDAP users from this domain access to my Debian via Samba, Winbind and Kerberos, which works almost perfectly.

In fact, my problem is that it looks like my pam checks aren't used at all (I made a call to `pam_exec.so`, which only calls a script to log data, in the `/etc/pam.d/samba` file AND in the `/etc/pam.d/common-session`, and none of them runs...)

So, if anyone could give me a hint on how could I troubleshoot this problem, that would be nice :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure I understand your question because it appears to miss the crucial bit—exactly *when* and *in which cases* you expect the PAM subsystem to kick in when the users access your Debian server via the SMB/CIFS protocol.

But nevertheless I'll give it a go—to cite the `smb.conf(5)` manual page:

> `obey pam restrictions` (G)
>
> When Samba 3.0 is configured to enable PAM support (i.e. --with-pam), this
>   parameter will control whether or not Samba should obey PAM's account and
>   session management directives. The default behavior is to use PAM for clear
>   text authentication only and to ignore any account or session management.
>
> Note that Samba always ignores PAM for authentication in the case of
>   `encrypt passwords = yes`. The reason is that PAM modules cannot support
>   the challenge/response authentication mechanism needed in the presence of
>   SMB password encryption.
>
> Default: `obey pam restrictions = no`

So I guess you simply have samba not reaching for the PAM subsystem at all.

Comment: Well, thanks for your answer, even if it's just the documentation, looks like it was enough,...

I forgot this line here =>

 Note that Samba always ignores PAM for authentication in the case of   encrypt passwords = yes.